# Localizable.strings not translating phrase

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nsattributedstring

For some weird reason only part of the texts in the Localizable.strings translates properly. If the string contain more the 1 word (the english side), it won't be translated. I made sure it is the same string (copied and pasted)

```
"Login" = "כניסה"; //translates properly 
"Email" = "דואר אלקטרוני"; //translates properly 
"Password" = "סיסמא"; //translates properly 
"forgot password?" = "שכחת סיסמא?"; //translation does not work
"Sign up" = "הירשם"; //translation does not work
```

I use this extension:

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

and in the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.emailTextField.placeholder = "Email".localized
    self.passwordTextField.placeholder = "Password".localized
    self.loginButton.setTitle("Login".localized, for: .normal)
    self.signupButton.setTitle("Sign up".localized, for: .normal)
    self.forgetPasswordButton.setTitle("forgot password?", for: .normal)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you hook all as outlets and change their text with **NSLocalizedString** ?? , or use **Main.strings** IB file ??

Comment: Test for potential character coding issues introduced by your space. You may want to re-type the words just in case there is an issue.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I've updated the question

Comment: You do not localize "forgot password?" and it appears you underline Sign up, perhaps that is why?

Comment: @CodeBender You were right. The "Sign up" and "forgot password" are attributes strings and need to be set like this let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Sign up".localized,
                                                        attributes: yourAttributes)
        self.signupButton.setAttributedTitle(attributeString, for: .normal). Wanna add this as an answer?

Comment: @Luda Done, happy it pointed you towards a fix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the appearance of Sign up having an underline, it looks like you have an `NSAttributedString`, which you then confirmed in your follow up comment.

While your code section here for "**forgot password?**" does not include the `localize` call you use elsewhere in your `viewDidLoad`, it turns out that you also identified this as an attributed string.

```
self.forgetPasswordButton.setTitle("forgot password?", for: .normal)
```

As you noted in your comment, this was corrected by applying the localization to the attributed string:

```
let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Sign up".localized, 
                                                attributes: yourAttributes) 
self.signupButton.setAttributedTitle(attributeString, for: .normal)
```